# PHP while loop duplicates one MySQL result

Tags: php, html, mysql

I apologize on the title as it's hard to word. All of the results look perfectly fine, until the end. After 25 items, the very first item repeats itself like 20 times and for the life of me I can't find any similar issues on here.

This is my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT NewsID, Link, Title, Thumbnail FROM `scinews` WHERE Subject = '".$articles."' AND Page = ".$page;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {                         
    
    echo '<div class="card">'.$row[3].'<p><div class="card-title">'.$row[2].'</p>
        <p><a href="'.$row[1].'"> [Read More]</a></p></div></div>';
}
```

If I remove that echo and replace it with this:

```
echo '<a href="'.$row[1].'">'.$row[2].'</a><br>';
```

The issue no longer exists. I thought the issue was related to MySQL so I tried switching from mysqli_fetch_assoc to mysqli_fetch_row, and even setting a LIMIT on the mysql command. Neither did anything. It seems to be related to the DIVs, but I'm just guessing a this point. Any help appreciated.

Comment: remove `$`$row[3]

Comment: No dice:

             echo '<div class="card"><div class="card-title">'.$row[2].'</div>
                <p><a href="'.$row[1].'" target="_blank"> [Read More]</a></p></div>';

Comment: just echo `$sql` what you get in this plz let me know?

Comment: so finally exactly what you want?

Comment: There's nothing in the code that will duplicate the results. Are you sure they aren't duplicated in the database?

Comment: Why do you have two `$` in `$$row[3]`?

Comment: There is no two $ in the query. That was a formatting issue in here.

This is the $sql only = SELECT DISTINCT NewsID, Link, Title, Thumbnail FROM `scinews` WHERE Subject = 'Science' AND Page = 1

The results look fine until the end. Results 1-25 display fine, but after 25 items it repeats the first row many times. @Dharman - users cannot input data.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether users can input data or not. SQL injection is about SQL not user input.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem.

There was a function in the javascript that was cloning the "card" class:

```
function cloneCards(count) {

  var main = document.querySelector("main");
  var card = document.querySelector(".card");

  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    main.appendChild(card.cloneNode(true));
  }  
}
```

The function was called when the user scrolled down and the header would shrink itself. So it was duplicating a card already created 25 times.

```
CloneCards(25);
```